# How to resolve this error in nodejs Cannot Post / error in Nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am new to nodejs I am facing this error and I am not able to resolve this.# in the url represents the specific div tag. And all the credentials are correct.I tried with extended:false also but then also the same error is coming.And also only Rendered is getting printed on the console.

** NODE JS CODE**

```
const express = require('express')
var session=require('express-session');
const {spawn} = require('child_process');
const path = require("path");
const app = express()
const router = express.Router();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.get('/', function (req, res)
{
    res.render('home_v3.html');
        console.log("Rendered")
    });
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 
//app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.post('/#topcities', function(req, res) {
console.log("POST");
  console.log(req.body)
  let body = '';
  body=req.body;
  res.redirect('/download');
});
app.get('/download', callD_alembert);
function callD_alembert(req, res) {
console.log("To python")
var
    config = {
        host: 'hostname',
        username: 'userid',
        password: 'pass',
        readyTimeout: 20000,
    },
    command = 'python3 topnew.py "' + body+'"';
exec(config, command, function (error) {
    if (error) {
        throw error;
    }
    console.log("Success");
    res.redirect('/new')
  });
}
app.get('/new', (req, res) => {
    var dataToSend;
 // spawn new child process to call the python script
 //console.log('Start')
 res.send("Hello")
})
app.listen(3000, '127.0.0.1')
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<div id="topcities">
<div class="row my-3"> 
      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <div id="country_table" style="height: 600px;width:500px;border:1px solid #ccc;font:16px/26px Georgia, Garamond, Serif;overflow:auto;"">
           
            <div>
            <form action="/" method="post">
                <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search Country Name" class="w3-border w3-round w3-margin-right" onkeyup="check_text_table(this.value)" style="width: 100%;height:50% float: left; padding: 4px; margin-bottom: : 2px;background-color:#edebeb";color:#ffffff>

<table id="mer_ctry_table" class="w3-table  -bordered w3-border">
                    <tr class="w3-light_grey">
                        <th></th>
                        <th>City</th>
                        <th>Country</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td onclick= 'check_toggle(this.childNodes[0]), addToList()'><input type='checkbox'  name='Agra India'><label></label></td><td>Agra</td><td>India</td></tr>
                    <tr><td onclick= 'check_toggle(this.childNodes[0]), addToList()'><input type='checkbox'  name='Ahmedabad India'><label></label></td><td>Ahmedabad</td><td>India</td></tr>
                    </table>
                    
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br/>
                <div class="submit" style=" padding-left:100px;">
                <input type="submit" value="Download CSV">
                </div>
                
                    </form>
                    
                <br/><br/>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: hi @soumya,  can you add your HTML too. from where you're posting the data

Comment: @CodeBug added the html code

Comment: why can't you use this ` <form action="/topcities" method="post">` and `app.post('/topcities', function(req, res) {`

Comment: @CodeBug thanks! that error is resolved but now it is coming ReferenceError:body is not defined in the line where I specify python command.

Comment: How can I use this body to send argument to python??

Comment: `console.log(req.body)` what your getting in this console?

Comment: I am getting the values of the form

Comment: check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const express = require('express')
var session=require('express-session');
const {spawn} = require('child_process');
const path = require("path");
const app = express()
const router = express.Router();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var bodydata;  //making a global variable,
app.post('/topcities', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body)
  bodydata = req.body; //changed let body to let bodydata
  res.redirect('/download');
 });
```

`body` is the express predefined variable we can't set that by making let or var,
[read here](https://devdocs.io/express/) for more to know, Instead of body use bodydata, hope this may solve your problem.

Comment: Again it is giving the error ReferenceError:bodydata is not defined in line pythom3 top new.py "' + bodydata+'"';

Comment: I guess u made a spelling mistake `ReferenceError:bofydata`

Comment: And when I make bodydata global as empty string it takes in python the empty string.

Comment: @CodeBugs no there was a spelling mistake in writing the comment but not in code

Comment: happy to help.. happy coding:-)